# onchange file input change img src and change image color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, opencart, cpanel

onchange event is not working. What am I supposed to do to get result on same page. I dont want to redirect to any other page to upload image. Is this issue is because of opencart? I dont know if it is correct to write like this in cpanel. I am using opencart and cpanel. Is there any other way?

**HTML**

```
 <input type='file' id="upload" onchange="readURL(this.value)" />
    <img id="img" src="#" alt="your image" />
```

**script**

```
function readURL(input) {
var url = input.value;
var ext = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
if (input.files && input.files[0]&& (ext == "gif" || ext == "png" || ext == "jpeg" || ext == "jpg")) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#img').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
else{
     $('#img').attr('src', '/assets/no_preview.png');
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Junkie/stN8U/)

Comment: has your problem solved

Comment: @logan yes. http://jsfiddle.net/stN8U/1/ this solved my problem Thank you.

Comment: if the answer provided is helpful accept the answer which suites you better.

Answer (score 54):

You need to send `this` object only instead of `this.value` while calling onchange

```
<input type='file' id="upload" onchange="readURL(this)" />
```

because you are using `input` variable as `this` in your function, like at line

```
var url = input.value;// reading value property of input element
```

**[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/stN8U/2/)**

**EDIT** - Try using jQuery like below --

remove onchange from input field :

```
<input type='file' id="upload" >
```

Bind `onchange` event to input field :

```
$(function(){
  $('#upload').change(function(){
    var input = this;
    var url = $(this).val();
    var ext = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
    if (input.files && input.files[0]&& (ext == "gif" || ext == "png" || ext == "jpeg" || ext == "jpg")) 
     {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
           $('#img').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
       reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
    else
    {
      $('#img').attr('src', '/assets/no_preview.png');
    }
  });

});
```

**[jQuery Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stN8U/3/)**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/M3kj6/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/stN8U/1/ both works well for me. Thank you. and also any suggestions for how to change image color only flash or photoshop is option for this or is there any other option??

Comment: yes this will work, ultimately you are binding change event to file input and calling function (which do rest of the task). The same thing I mentioned in my answer but put all code inside bind function and not in seperate javascrpt function.

Answer (score 49):

**Simple Solution. No Jquery**

```html
<img id="output" src="" width="100" height="100">

<input name="photo" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="document.getElementById('output').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])">
```

Comment: In some cases, the image does not update straightaway. If I add some more code to the event `onchange`, it might run on the previous copy of the image. Is there a way to wait for the image to upload?

Answer (score 11):

in your HTML : `<input type="file" id="yourFile">`
don't forget to reference your js file or put the following script between `<script></script>`
in your script :

```
var fileToRead = document.getElementById("yourFile");

fileToRead.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    var files = fileToRead.files;
    if (files.length) {
        console.log("Filename: " + files[0].name);
        console.log("Type: " + files[0].type);
        console.log("Size: " + files[0].size + " bytes");
    }

}, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with this code, you will get the image preview while uploading

```
<input type='file' id="upload" onChange="readURL(this);"/>
<img id="img" src="#" alt="your image" />

 function readURL(input){
 var ext = input.files[0]['name'].substring(input.files[0]['name'].lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
if (input.files && input.files[0] && (ext == "gif" || ext == "png" || ext == "jpeg" || ext == "jpg")) 
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#img').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}else{
     $('#img').attr('src', '/assets/no_preview.png');
}
}
```

Comment: This answer is the same as [the main answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24837700/2074077), basically stole it from the solution provider for points. Not cool imo.

Answer (score 2):

```
Below solution tested and its working, hope it will support in your project.
HTML code:
    <input type="file" name="asgnmnt_file" id="asgnmnt_file" class="span8" 
    style="display:none;" onchange="fileSelected(this)">
    <br><br>
    <img id="asgnmnt_file_img" src="uploads/assignments/abc.jpg" width="150" height="150" 
    onclick="passFileUrl()" style="cursor:pointer;">

JavaScript code:
    function passFileUrl(){
    document.getElementById('asgnmnt_file').click();
    }

    function fileSelected(inputData){
    document.getElementById('asgnmnt_file_img').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(inputData.files[0])
    }
```