# Update image as file is chosen

Tags: javascript, html

[image: The image file name is 'default.jpg']]

I want that when the button for change picture is clicked an input `type=file` opens up and as soon as the image is selected the image `src` is updated. How can I achieve this? I am using PHP as the server side language and trying to do on web page.

Comment: Some code to show of what you've tried so far...?

Comment: Not enough information. For example: are you trying to do it in web? What server side tech. are you using (PHP, Node.js etc.)? Or is it an HTML/JavaScript based desktop / mobile app? Nothing is clear from your question.

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I know how to show input type=file on clicking of button but I have no idea how to update the img as soon as file is chosen.

Comment: Read the file using [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) and `.readAsDataURL` method. Then use the value returned by the said method as `src` of an image.

Comment: Simplest solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56777541/8240417

Answer (score 5):

You can doit using HTML5 FileReader. You don't need to use PHP or server side for that.

See this JSFidlle: https://jsfiddle.net/166p3uqk/1/

You don't need a FORM or value to your INPUT text.

**HTML:**

```
<input onchange=file_changed() type=file id=input>
<img id=img>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function file_changed(){
  var selectedFile = document.getElementById('input').files[0];
  var img = document.getElementById('img')

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(){
     img.src = this.result
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);
 }
```

---

**More info:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader
- https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

Comment: I also want to add the image file name to the server. How can it be done for the same above code?

Comment: The image filename will be sent to your server. Please accept the answer if it fill your requirements

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you need the image to be uploaded to server first or not But just for front-end it could be done by:

```
<input type="file" class="changeimage" id="changeimage" accept="image/*"/>
<img class="image" src="default.png" style="height:120px"/>
<script>
    document.getElementById("changeimage").addEventListener("change", function(){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            document.getElementById("image").setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
        }

    });
</script>
```

You can also find a solution at [onchange file input change img src and change image color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837646/onchange-file-input-change-img-src-and-change-image-color)

Good Luck:)